# MatLab: Not Enough Eigenvectors for (Repeated) Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-equations

I am trying to make a code that matches the eigenvalues to eigenvectors for one of my projects and I am new to MatLab. I get a 3x3 matrix output when it comes to eigenvalues and a 3x2 when it comes to eigenvectors. I know the issues lies within the fact that one of my eigenvalues is a repeat, but I cannot find any resources telling me how to fix this. My V should definitely be a 3x3 matrix unless I have completely done this wrong when I did it by hand.

When n=2, my answer is how I want and my code works.

```
% Case n=2.
clear
syms k1 c1 c2 lambda t
A=[-k1 0; k1 0];
[V,D]=eig(A) %V is the eigenvectors, D is the eigenvalues.
p0=[1 0];
eqn11 = c1*V(1,1)+c2*V(1,2) == p0(1,1);
eqn12 = c1*V(2,1)+c2*V(2,2) == p0(1,2);
solcon = solve([eqn11,eqn12], [c1, c2]);
c1Sol=solcon.c1;
c2Sol=solcon.c2;
exp(D(1,1)*t)*c1Sol*V(:,1) + exp(D(2,2)*t)*c2Sol*V(:,2)
```

However, when n=3, I get an error.

```
% Case n=3.
clear
syms k1 c1 c2 c3 lambda t
B=[-k1 0 0; k1 -k1 0; 0 k1 0]
[V,D]=eig(B) %V is the eigenvectors, D is the eigenvalues.
p0=[1 0 0];
eqn21 = c1*V(1,1)+c2*V(1,2)+c3*V(1,3) == p0(1,1);
eqn22 = c1*V(2,1)+c2*V(2,2)+c3*V(2,3) == p0(1,2);
eqn23 = c1*V(3,1)+c2*V(3,2)+c3*V(3,3) == p0(1,3);
solcon = solve([eqn21, eqn22, eqn23], [c1, c2,c3]);
c1Sol=solcon.c1;
c2Sol=solcon.c2;
c3Sol=solcon.c3;
exp(D(1,1)*t)*c1Sol*V(:,1) + exp(D(2,2)*t)*c2Sol*V(:,2)+exp(D(3,3)*t)*c3Sol*V(:,3)
```

V should be a 3x3, right? Please help. Perhaps my code for n=2 is wrong as well and I just lucked out.

Comment: A matrix can simply not have enough eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue. Then it isn't diagonalizable. Depending on your application, there are ways around it, but none of them will give you that second eigenvector, because it just doesn't exist.

Comment: It has been quite some time since I took linear algebra. Does this mean that there are only two eigenvalues that apply (as in, my by-hand method was incorrect), or does this mean that MatLab can simply not do what I want?

Comment: Try your $n=2$ code with `[0 k1;0 0]` instead. You won’t have enough eigenvectors there, either. As @MattSamuel points out, not every matrix is diagonalizable. You’ll need to do something else to compute exponentials for those matrices. See “Jordan normal form” for a general method.

Comment: MATLAB can do what you need, but you’re going to have to use the Jordan decomposition of the matrix, or something similar. I’m sure that there’s a built-in function for computing the exponential of a matrix, for that matter.

Comment: @hgasu It's true that matlab can't find two eigenvectors for that eigenvalue. But that's not matlab's fault. Only one exists. Nothing can change that. It's like asking for a positive real number $x$ such that $2x=0$.

Comment: @MattSamuel, thank you for your help. One last question: so this essentially can mean that my repeated eigenvalues, lambda=0,-k1 where -k1 has multiplicity two, can just be considered as two eigenvalues and two eigenvectors? Basically, ignore the repeat?

Comment: @hgasu I'm not sure what you mean by "ignore." The eigenvalue has multiplicity $2$, but only one eigenvector. So there are three eigenvalues with multiplicity, and two eigenvectors. That doesn't mean the multiplicity goes away. It's of theoretical importance that that eigenspace is deficient, because it means you can't diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: @MattSamuel I suppose what I mean is, I am trying to write out the equation; the equation will only have to eigenvector components since the third is not possible?

Comment: $[0  0  1]^T + k_1*e^{-k_1*t}*t*[0 1 -1]^T$, @MattSamuel - is this the sufficient equation, is my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @hgasu Yes. If it can find the eigenvalues, it should be able to find all of the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

The "secret" is to use the kernel of $B-\lambda_k I$ for the different eigenvalues $\lambda_k$.

Let me explain it on a numerical example :

```
B=[2 1 1
   1 2 1
   1 1 2];
eig(B),% gives 1 (double eigenvalue) and 4 (which is simple)
I=eye(3);
null(B-1*I), % provides a basis of 2 vectors for the eigenspace associated with $\lambda_1=1$
null(B-4*I), % provides a unique vector generating the eigenspace associated with $\lambda_1=1$
```